# what does "OLE The application called an interface that was marshalled for a different thread" after calling RevokeDragDrop mean?

Tags: c++, com, ole

I'm still trying to figure out the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10697991/hooking-explorer-drag-drop-fails). I would appreciate a nudge in the right direction (since I have very little experience in OLE). Did anyone encounter a similar error after calling RevokDragDrop?

thanks,

Comment: Could you please upload your code somewhere? I wasted the whole day now trying to figure out how this works ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You passed marshaled interface into a different apartment. An attempt to call a method revealed this and the call aborted with this error `RPC_E_WRONG_THREAD`.

You should be careful using interface pointers on multiple threads. If you intend to use a pointer that you already hold from a different thread, you have to think it over whether you are allowed to or you need explicitly marshal/unmarshal the pointer for such use, e.g. with `CoMarshalInterThreadInterfaceInStream` function.

I suppose that the source of the problem is `GetProp`/`SetProp` API used. Those store raw pointers as they are without marshaling necessary on the way.

Comment: Thanks, I think I understand the problem. If I understand correctly, I have to marshal the interface from the thread holding it (not possible in my case - I don't control that thread). Do you think SetProp(OleDropTargetInterface) has any chance of working here (or is just a fancy way of crashing the process)?

Comment: If you are hooking IE window, maybe you can create hidden window in the thread of explorer, or install message hook there. You can receive messages through it and handle them in context of IE, on right thread. Passing a COM pointer as a windows property is not quite safe, it is basically safe within a thread only.